# Two different applications with the same ApplicationData folder

Tags: c#

I have two different applications that need to exchange data. The first one is a service and the second one is a GUI.
I want to use the ApplicationData folder for this purpose.

Is there a way to get the same path using `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` for these two applications?

Comment: Second application is GUID? What do you mean?

Comment: Consider that data exchange between applications is a solved problem in a variety of ways, is there a specific reason you want to use a shared folder to exchange data with the issues that may arise from doing so (file locks immediately spring to mind)?

Comment: If you want ipc try shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is the same for different applications as long as they run under the same user account. That is why you usually put data not directly into this folder but into a  subfolder with your company name and product name.

The problem you have is that your service runs under a different user. You can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` to get a path that is the same for all applications and all users. In order to not collide with other applications, store data in a subfolder with your company name.

```
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
    path = Path.Combine(path, "MyCompanyName");

    // Use path  to store / read data shared by all your applications
```

Pay special attention to the fact that all users on your computer share that folder. So you cannot use this approach if you have multiple instances of your GUI application running under different user accounts and you don't want them to share data. (Unless you put some effort into implementing a mechanism that each application instance only accesses the data it is meant to access)

But also look at what James Thorpe has written: There are usually better ways to exchange data between different processes running concurrently on the same computer than using files.